# validation for alphabetical input only in C

Tags: c, cs50

I am having trouble accepting only alphabetic characters from the command line argument argv[1]. If I insert letters followed by numbers this is accepted as valid input but I need to only accept letters. Therefore if a user inputs something like: "Jack23" I need this to show up as the same error as "32214" would. As of right now it accepts inputs when the beginning character is a letter as if the whole string is composed of letters even when numbers are present. Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    string plain_text;
    string key = argv[1];

    if (argc == 2)
    {
        // checks each character from second argument to see if it is an alphabetical character
        for (int i = 0, k = strlen(key); i < k; i++)
        {
            //if a non-alphabetical character is detected, the user is reprompted to enter a valid key
            if (!isalpha(key[i]))
            {
                printf("error, non alphabetic input detected, please input valid key");
                return 1;
            }

            // if user enters correct alphabetical key then we proceed with the request for valid plain text
            else
            {
                plain_text = get_string("plaintext: ");
            }

        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("error, please input two arguments! Ex: ./test Try");
    }

}
```

Comment: What is `string argv[]`? Wishful thinking? That's not what `string.h` usually does. Is it from `cs50.h`? I am kind of concerned by any C course that obscures what C strings actually are. Is `char*` that scary?

Comment: You want to move `plain_text = get_string("plaintext: ");` outside of validation loop.

Comment: It may also help to explain your intended behavior with multiple examples.

Comment: I'll reiterate what @tadman posted:  do not use CS50's `string`.  Ever.  It's obfuscating a fundamental data type in C.  I'd say anyone promoting that probably has problems spelling C and IMO shouldn't be caught anywhere near the teaching of programming.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply! I am not sure I am still trying to understand  a lot of things related to the c language as I just started taking this course online. What would I need to do for char*? I do believe string argv[] may be from the cs50.h but am not sure. thanks

Comment: The normal signature is `int main(int argc, char** argv)` but some variation is allowed, like `char* argv[]` instead. I find the `[]` notation gives people the mistaken impression this is like a Java array, which it's absolutely not. Is this a course you're committed to completing for academic reasons, or is it something from a point of more casual interest? There are likely far better courses than this one.

Comment: @tadman it's synonymous to `char *argv[]` because the fiends at Harvard start their CS students out with `cs50.h`, which exercises pure genius by putting `typedef char *string;` in that header. I swear on my career that header and the functions that library provide have done 10x more to *hinder* proper learning of C than they ever helped. Seriously. I *hate* that header and lib, and am constantly amazed how often it surfaces on this site.

Comment: @WhozCraig Between that and the brutality of inflicting Turbo C++ for DOS on people in this age I'm sometimes amazed people learn anything at all.

Comment: I don't have the cs50.h header (I guess this is where your `string` datatype and the `get_string` function come from), but the loop itself is fine and works correctly.

Comment: @tadman They are not. I can confirm I learnt C (well, I think I did) only after couple of years of monitoring SO "C" tag...

Comment: @tadman Think of the poor fellow residing in a small village outside of Bangalore that is taking an online cut of the harvard class, while using quarter-century-old Turbo C to do it. Man, I feel for that guy.

Comment: @WhozCraig That's what fills me with dismay. The most destitute person in Bangalore working on an anemic fifteen year old laptop could *still* be running a current version of Linux and the latest compilers. There's no reason to exhume something like Turbo C from the dustbin of history.

Comment: @tadman This was a course I started to get an introduction into the feel of what computer science would be like. I will starting college courses this upcoming fall. I do feel like the course gives a lot of useful info but also doesn't explain things needed for the problems they assign.

Comment: It's great you're trying to get a head-start on things. The trouble is there's far too many awful C courses. What's important is to have a solid reference book (e.g. [*the* book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language)) and one or more introductions that can help you navigate and understand some of the concepts. [Pluralsight](https://www.pluralsight.com) or [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org) will generally have far better quality material than some random YouTube video or online course.

Comment: @tadman thanks for the information I will check it out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As of right now it accepts inputs when the beginning character is a letter as if the whole string is composed of letters even when numbers are present.

Your problem is this loop, where I removed the comments to make the problem clear:

```
for (int i = 0, k = strlen(key); i < k; i++)
{
    if (!isalpha(key[i]))
    {
        printf("error, non alphabetic input detected, please input valid key");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        plain_text = get_string("plaintext: ");
    }
}
```

That loop will call `get_string("plaintext: ")` immediately upon finding an alphabetic character in the string.

You want to move the `else` part out of the loop and let the loop verify the *entire* input string.

```
for (int i = 0, k = strlen(key); i < k; i++)
{
    if (!isalpha(key[i]))
    {
        printf("error, non alphabetic input detected, please input valid key");
        return 1;
    }
}

plain_text = get_string("plaintext: ");
```